# Why does "sock.recv(1024)" outside "while True:" return the service running on the port, like nmap does?

Tags: python, sockets, nmap

I am confused as to why `sock.recv()` returns the name of service running on the particular port. Here is what I mean.
When you code in python and connect to a server, you normally do it inside `while True` loop to receive whatever that's been sent by the other computer. But when you just do `recv()` one time spontaneously, to a server , say `192.168.55.3`, on the `port 22` that is running `ssh`, `sock.recv(1024)`  returns the name of application like `ssh version xxx` 
I don't understand the mechanism behind this and hope someone can explain.

I did do some research but could not find much.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((interface, port))
sock.connect((host, host_port))
print(sock.recv(100))
```

it returns something like this `b'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1\n`

Comment: Because you connected to that service and that's what it sent you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some network protocols the server sends a message to the client as soon as a connection is established. This message may identify the version of the protocol, the name of the software running the service, the name of the machine and the operating system it runs etc

The purpose of the message can vary from enabling the client to decide if it connected to the right server and is able to communicate with it, to simple vanity/advertising.

Protocols that do this include SSH, SMTP, and FTP. Try connecting to different ports and you'll get very different results

Answer (score 1):

### You are connecting to port 22, which is used for the **SSH (Secure Shell) protocol**.

Per [RFC 4253: The Secure Shell (SSH) Transport Layer Protocol, Section 4: "Connection Setup"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4):

> SSH works over any 8-bit clean, binary-transparent transport. The underlying transport SHOULD protect against transmission errors, as such errors cause the SSH connection to terminate. The client initiates the connection.
>
> 4.1. Use over TCP/IP
>
> **When used over TCP/IP, the server normally listens for connections on port 22**. This port number has been registered with the IANA, and has been officially assigned for SSH.
>
> 4.2. Protocol Version Exchange
>
> **When the connection has been established, both sides MUST send an identification string**. This identification string MUST be
>
> SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF
>
> Since the protocol being defined in this set of documents is version 2.0, the 'protoversion' MUST be "2.0". The 'comments' string is OPTIONAL. If the 'comments' string is included, a 'space' character (denoted above as SP, ASCII 32) MUST separate the 'softwareversion' and 'comments' strings. The identification MUST be terminated by a single Carriage Return (CR) and a single Line Feed (LF) character (ASCII 13 and 10, respectively). Implementers who wish to maintain Ylonen & Lonvick Standards Track [Page 4] RFC 4253 SSH Transport Layer Protocol January 2006 compatibility with older, undocumented versions of this protocol may want to process the identification string without expecting the presence of the carriage return character for reasons described in Section 5 of this document. The null character MUST NOT be sent. The maximum length of the string is 255 characters, including the Carriage Return and Line Feed.
>
> The part of the identification string preceding the Carriage Return and Line Feed is used in the Diffie-Hellman key exchange (see Section 8).
>
> The server MAY send other lines of data before sending the version string. Each line SHOULD be terminated by a Carriage Return and Line Feed. Such lines MUST NOT begin with "SSH-", and SHOULD be encoded in ISO-10646 UTF-8 [RFC3629] (language is not specified). Clients MUST be able to process such lines. Such lines MAY be silently ignored, or MAY be displayed to the client user. If they are displayed, control character filtering, as discussed in [SSH-ARCH], SHOULD be used. The primary use of this feature is to allow TCP- wrappers to display an error message before disconnecting.
>
> Both the 'protoversion' and 'softwareversion' strings MUST consist of printable US-ASCII characters, with the exception of whitespace characters and the minus sign (-). The 'softwareversion' string is primarily used to trigger compatibility extensions and to indicate the capabilities of an implementation. The 'comments' string SHOULD contain additional information that might be useful in solving user problems. As such, an example of a valid identification string is
>
> SSH-2.0-billsSSH_3.6.3q3<CR><LF>
>
> This identification string does not contain the optional 'comments' string and is thus terminated by a CR and LF immediately after the 'softwareversion' string.
>
> Key exchange will begin immediately after sending this identifier. All packets following the identification string SHALL use the binary packet protocol, which is described in Section 6.

What you are seeing being printed out is the server's identification string:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1
```

Where:

- protoversion = `2.0`
- softwareversion = `OpenSSH_4.7p1`
- comments = `Debian-8ubuntu1`